# Como especificar a demanda no lpSolveAPI em R?

Tags: r

Eu estou tentando otimizar o lucro por 4 produtos diferentes, um que lucra 600reais/unidade  outro que lucra 550/unidade outro que lucra  400/unidade e outro que lucra 300/unidade.
Porem a demanda pelo x1 = 50 pelo x2 = 50 pelo x3 = 80 e pelo x4 = 120.

Como eu especifico a demanda individual de cada dentro do lpSolveAPI??

```
library(lpSolveAPI)
lprec <- make.lp(0,4) #numero de linhas e de variaveis de decisao
lp.control(lprec,sense='max') #maximzar ou minimizar
set.objfn(lprec, c(600, 550, 400, 300)) # funcao objetivo
add.constraint(lprec, c(31540, 40000, 29600, 14700), "<=", 108000) #restricao 1
add.constraint(lprec, c(36290,22500,42550,7350), "<=", 110000) #restricao 2
add.constraint(lprec, c(19000, 11250,11840,16800), "<=", 60000) #restricao 3

solve(lprec) #resolver ppl
get.objective(lprec) #funcao objetivo resolvida
get.variables(lprec) #qto de cada variavel otimiza o sistema
get.constraints(lprec)
lprec
```

Answer (score 1):

O pacote `lpSolveAPI` aceita restrições de três tipos, `"<="`, `">="` e `"="`. Creio que na pergunta a demanda deve ser entendida com *demanda máxima*, não como demanda fixa. Então as restrições a serem usadas serão de menoridade, `"<="`

```
#x1 = 50, pelo x2 = 50, pelo x3 = 80 e pelo x4 = 120
add.constraint(lprec, 1, "<=", 50, indices = 1) #restricao 4a
add.constraint(lprec, 1, "<=", 50, indices = 2) #restricao 4b
add.constraint(lprec, 1, "<=", 80, indices = 3) #restricao 4c
add.constraint(lprec, 1, "<=", 120, indices = 4) #restricao 4d
```

Agora resolve-se o problema tal como está na pergunta. As soluções serão dadas por `get.variables(lprec)`.

```
solve(lprec) #resolver ppl
#[1] 0

get.objective(lprec) #funcao objetivo resolvida
#[1] 1948.62

get.variables(lprec) #qto de cada variavel otimiza o sistema
#[1] 2.6654343 0.5221156 0.0000000 0.2073184
```

Verificar estas soluções multiplicando os coeficientes da função objetivo pelo vetor solução.

```
c(600, 550, 400, 300) %*% get.variables(lprec)
#        [,1]
#[1,] 1948.62
```